# Convert char array to Unicode

Tags: c++, visual-c++, device-driver, wdk, nt-native-api

I am developing a device driver in Visual C++.
I need to convert a character array to Unicode as well as
wide character array in my driver.

Pointer to useful functions will be appreciated.
I know "RtlInitUnicodeString" which concerts wchar to Unicode
but need help for conversion of simple character arrays.

Comment: What is the encoding of your "character array"? Which Unicode encoding do you want in output?

Comment: If it is a char array then the encoding could already be Unicode (UTF-8). PS the term Unicode is not an encoding it is a general description of character codepoints. It can be encoded in a couple of different ways (UTF-8/16/32)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are ok with the "current system locale" setting for the input encoding and the output in the usual UTF-16, the [RtlAnsiStringToUnicodeString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648413%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) should be available in kernel-mode.

Comment: First converted the character array to ANSI_STRING using "RtlInitAnsiString()" and then used RtlAnsiStringToUnicodeString().